# TypeError: create_order() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, api, binance

I am trying to place an order at Binance with the script below, but get this back:

```
TypeError: create_order() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is the script's code:

```py
symbol = 'EOSUSDT'
TradeCoin = symbol
Decision = 'SIDE_BUY'
Assets =1
Price = 30

OrderLine = 'symbol=%s, side=%s, type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET, quantity=%s, price=%s'
message = (OrderLine % (TradeCoin, Decision, Assets, Price))

print(message)
order = client.create_order(message)
```

Comment: This is Python, right? You should add it to the tags at least, this way it will properly be highlighted. Or, better yet, highlight it yourself in a code block.

Comment: Yes, your are right, I should make it clear, that it is written  in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
tradePair = 'SUNBTC'
order = client.order_limit_sell(
symbol=tradePair,
quantity=0.200,
price= 0.000700,
newClientOrderId= 'ALPC')
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it would be good if you provide some explanation on how your code works.